# ionic slidebox issue after ajax call

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm firing an `AJAX` call to get an array of news items from a web service and display it in an `ion-slidebox` in my mobile app.

**HTML**

```
  <div  style="z-index:1000;margin-bottom:0px;position:absolute;width:100%" ng-if="!newsView"  ng-controller="PlaylistsCtrl" ng-init="getNews();">


                          <ion-slide-box show-pager="false" does-continue="true" auto-play="true"  style="width: inherit; height: 40px;" >

                                            <ion-slide ng-repeat="item in slides">


                                            <p class="news_titles" ng-click="news()" style="z-index:0; margin-top: -80px; height: 65px;" >{{item.subject}}</p>


                                            </ion-slide>


                          </ion-slide-box>


                </div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
.controller('PlaylistsCtrl', ['$scope', '$ionicModal','ngProgress','$timeout','$interval', '$ionicSlideBoxDelegate','$state','$http','$rootScope','$ionicScrollDelegate',
                              function ($scope, $ionicModal, ngProgress,$timeout, $interval, $ionicSlideBoxDelegate, $state,$http,$rootScope,$ionicScrollDelegate) {







    $scope.index = 0;

    $scope.data = {};


                             // $scope.slides = []; -- 1
                            //  $scope.slides = [{subject:""},{subject:""}]; -- 2

                              $scope.getNews = function (){

                              $timeout(function() {

                              $scope.url =   $rootScope.rootScopeBaseUrl + $rootScope.rootScopeWebServiceUrls.NEWS_CSR;



                              $http.get($scope.url ,{ headers: {jauthtoken : $rootScope.rootScopeAuthenticationToken, jaccesstoken:$rootScope.rootScopeAccessToken}
                                        })
                              .success(function(data, status, headers, config){



                                       if(status==200){

                                       $scope.slides = data;
                                      $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.update();


                                       } else {

                                       }

                                       })
                              .error(function(data,status,headers,config){

                                     console.log(data);
                                     console.log(status);
                                     });

                              }, 50);


                              };

      ])
```

But when using `$scope.slides = [];` to initialise the array, the slide-box auto-plays for one loop and then stops without continuing.

And when using  `$scope.slides = [{subject:""},{subject:""}]` to initialise array would keep on auto-playing the slide-box,  but the initial blank values are shown too, almost as if the data array returned from AJAX call is appended to `$scope.slides`.

What I want to accomplish is to auto-play the slide-box with the content received from the `AJAX` call continuously.

Please help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: did you find a solution for this? i'm having a similar issue